# Why won't my switch statement work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

```js
var num = prompt("Enter your number");
switch (num) {
  case (num % 2 == 0):
    alert("the number is divisible by 2");
    break;
  case (num % 3 == 0):
    alert("the number is divisible by 3");
    break;
  default:
    alert("the number is not divisible by either 2 or 3");
    break;
 }
```

I try to get the number that is divisible by 2 and 3, but on my console, I always get a default value.

Comment: Please format your code so that it is legible. You might use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon has `<>` in it in the toolbar).

Comment: `num` will never be equal to `(num % 2) == 0` (for example), because `(num % 2) == 0` will be `true` or `false`, and no number is `===` `true` or `false` (`switch` uses strict equality when checking the test value against the case expression results). You *could* use `switch (true)`, but really, this should just be an `if`/`else if`/`else`.

Comment: "_I try to get the number that is divisible by 2 and 3_", can you provide an example?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### Use if-then, not case

switch-case is used with an expression that has several values, e.g. `switch(a)`, followed by a series of `case` options for various values of a.

What you have is a series of *conditions* that you want tested one-after-another. For that, use a series of `if`-`then`s.

```js
var num = prompt("Enter your number");
console.log(num)

if (num % 2 == 0) {
  alert("the number is divisible by 2");
} else if (num % 3 == 0) {
  alert("the number is divisible by 3");
} else {
  alert("the number is not divisible by either 2 or 3");
}
```

Comment: There are **so many** previous versions of this question. *(Not my downvote.)*